# "The cold months" vs. "The months of cold/coldness" ahead can really take their toll on [...]

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is it okay to replace "the cold months" with "the months of cold/coldness" in the following sentence? If not in the following context, then in what context can "the months of cold/coldness" be used?

"[If you don't take precautions,
the cold months ahead can
really take their toll on [...]](https://www.linguee.co/ingles-espanol/traduccion/cold+months+ahead.html)"

Thank you!

Comment: No, months of coldness doesn't sound great. Why not just leave well enough alone? "Months of coldness followed: he just could not bring himself to love her."

Comment: **Long months of searing heat on the planet gave way to equally long months of freezing cold.**

Comment: It's a style choice. "The months of cold/coldness" sounds more poetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are grammatically correct, but the shorter version ("cold months") is more common. English speakers tend to prefer more concise phrases. However, either version is easily understandable.

Comment: Thank you all so very much for your help!